# Testing library with react bootstrap (reads color incorrectly)

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-testing-library

Using react bootstrap, create-react-app and sass. I want to test the theme color I used is correctly rendered after loading a button component from react bootstrap.

My test picks up the color as "ButtonFace"...

I think that the issue is that with the render function it is picking up SASS/bootstrap variables as opposed to rendering the final output (the color). Not sure how to work around this for a test without using enzyme, if that's the solution.

Test.js

```
import React from "react";
import { render, waitFor, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import App from "../App";

test("loads and has access to the custom theme color", async () => {
  render(<App />);

  await waitFor(() => screen.getByRole("button"));

  expect(screen.getByRole("button")).toHaveStyle({
    "background-color": "#1C1842",
  });
});
```

App.js

```
import "./App.scss";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <Button>TEST</Button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Test error

```
 FAIL  src/tests/theme.test.js
  ● loads and has access to the custom theme color

    expect(element).toHaveStyle()

    - Expected

    - background-color: rgb(29, 120, 116);
    + background-color: ButtonFace;

      10 |   await waitFor(() => screen.getByRole("button"));
      11 |
    > 12 |   expect(screen.getByRole("button")).toHaveStyle({
         |                                      ^
      13 |     "background-color": "#1C1842",
      14 |   });
      15 | });
```